# Special Char. replacement for different countries

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently sitting on an excel macro which should replace different special characters for different countries.
Each country is replacing special char. another way.

E.g.:

- Germany is replacing the "Ä" with "AE"
- Belgium is replacing the "Ä"with "A"

Table looks like:

Column A: First Name

Column B: Mid Name

Column C: Last Name

Column D: Country

The Macro should check first, which country is listed in the excel and afterwards replace the Special Char. in Column A and C.

Actual code:

```
Sub UmlauteErsatezen()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet

    If cell D:D = "Germany" then
        For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            With Sh.UsedRange
                .Replace What:="Ö", Replacement:="oe", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
                .Replace What:="Ü", Replacement:="ue"
                .Replace What:="Ä", Replacement:="ae"

    else if cell D:D ="Belgium" then
       For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
           With Sh.UsedRange
                .Replace What:="Ö", Replacement:="o", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
                .Replace What:="Ü", Replacement:="u"
                .Replace What:="Ä", Replacement:="a"

    End If

End With

Next
End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas how I can do it ?

Comment: Your code seems to be working. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @Vityata really? I indented the code a bit, and it is full of errors. Several `Next` and `End With` are missing or in the wrong places. This won't even compile I think.

Comment: You're not terribly far off... In what sheet / cell do you have the country name (eg "Germany") stored?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - in a way :) - this parts `LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True` comes from macro-recorder, thus the OP can manage to do it by himself/herself.

Comment: @Atlantikdriver Please make sure that the code you show in your question is **exactly** the code you use. Several `End With` and `Next` statements are in the wrong place. Indent/format your code correctly so you can easily see it. Also add a screenshot of your sheet if possible (it is unclear which cell needs to be checked for the country.

Comment: @PEH - My idea is that the OP is probably wishing to make some kind of [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), thus trying to put the logic for the countries and the changes on a separate worksheet. Then accessing them through the code. But this is quite far as away from the code provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check, whether in cell D1 is written "Germany" then write this:

`If Range("D1") = "Germany" Then`

This `If cell D:D = "Germany" then` would give a compiling error.

Answer (score 2):

### You can either use `Select Case` or create tables to be used with VLOOKUP

#### `Select Case` approach example

```
Sub UmlauteErsatezen()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim vArr(), vArrSub()
    Dim i As Long
    
    For Each Sh In Thisworkbook.Worksheets
        For Each iCell in Sh.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
            Erase vArr : Erase vArrSub
            Select Case iCell.Value
                Case "Germany"
                    vArr = Array("Ö", "Ü", "Ä")
                    vArrSub = Array("oe", "ue", "ae")
                Case "Belgium"
                    vArr = Array("Ö", "Ü", "Ä")
                    vArrSub = Array("o", "u", "a")
                Case Else
                    'Think of something
            End Select
            For i = Lbound(vArr) To Ubound(vArr)
                Intersect(iCell.EntireRow, _
                          Sh.UsedRange).Replace vArr(i), _
                                                vArrSub(i), _
                                                xlPart
            Next i
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I do not state that these are the only approaches to answer the question.

Comment: `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` is a bit dangerous, as far as it ignores cells with formula. And in Excel, about half of the cells are like this.

Comment: @Vityata Yep, know that. I would roll with `Sh.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells` but I have no idea what kind of data he has and where it is located, not to mention if his tables have any headers.

Comment: Yup. But probably in the headers the `ü` should be replaced as well to `au`. Guessing...

Comment: @Vityata yes, that is what i wanted to do